# How to get Page Source of next page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, webdriver

What I'm trying to do is converting the driver to html in order to use beautiful soup. The problem is that the item that is being printed by the prettifier (aka the one in the driver) is the html of the login page, instead of the one that comes after (I know for sure that the login is succesful, as well as the navigation to the next page).

Is there a reason why the driver would contain the first page's source and not update to the one we navigated to?

This is my code:

```
import os
import random
import sys

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/followers/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.get(url)


username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="username"]')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="password"]')
login_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="_0mzm- sqdOP  L3NKy      "]')

username.send_keys("name")
password.send_keys("pass")

#login
login_btn.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,features="lxml")
print(soup.prettify())

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

`driver.implicitly_wait(2)` is useless in this case. You need to use [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits). For instance

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

login_btn.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_changes('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/gelsonfonteles/followers/')) #  pass exact URL of Login page
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,features="lxml")
```

`EC.url_changes` allows to wait for specified URL to change for something else.

You can also wait for some specific element to appear on desired page

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close. You just need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *visibility* of any of the elements on the page and can use `features="html.parser"` as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  url = 'https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/followers/'
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get(url)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']"))).send_keys("username")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']").send_keys("password")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Log in']").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[text()='gelsonfonteles']")))
  soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,features="html.parser")
  print(soup.prettify())
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html class="js logged-in client-root" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
    <title>
     Gelson Fonteles ???? (@gelsonfonteles) • Instagram photos and videos
    </title>
    <meta content="noimageindex, noarchive" name="robots"/>
    <meta content="yes" name="mobile-web-app-capable"/>
    <meta content="#000000" name="theme-color"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover" id="viewport" name="viewport"/>
    <link href="/data/manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>
    <link crossorigin="" href="https://graph.instagram.com" rel="preconnect"/>
    <link as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/static/bundles/metro/ProfilePageContainer.js/68f09467caf1.js" rel="preload" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script async="" src="https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/1425767024389221?v=2.8.35&amp;r=stable">
    </script>
    <script async="" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js">
    </script>
    <script id="facebook-jssdk" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     (function() {
    var docElement = document.documentElement;
    var classRE = new RegExp('(^|\\s)no-js(\\s|$)');
    var className = docElement.className;
    docElement.className = className.replace(classRE, '$1js$2');
  })();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     /*
   Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
  */

  (function(){function g(a,c){b||(b=a,f=c,h.forEach(function(a){removeEventListener(a,l,e)}),m())}function m(){b&amp;&amp;f&amp;&amp;0&lt;d.length&amp;&amp;(d.forEach(function(a){a(b,f)}),d=[])}function n(a,c){function k(){g(a,c);d()}function b(){d()}function d(){removeEventListener("pointerup",k,e);removeEventListener("pointercancel",b,e)}addEventListener("pointerup",k,e);addEventListener("pointercancel",b,e)}function l(a){if(a.cancelable){var c=performance.now(),b=a.timeStamp;b&gt;c&amp;&amp;(c=+new Date);c-=b;"pointerdown"==a.type?n(c,
  a):g(c,a)}}var e={passive:!0,capture:!0},h=["click","mousedown","keydown","touchstart","pointerdown"],b,f,d=[];h.forEach(function(a){addEventListener(a,l,e)});window.perfMetrics=window.perfMetrics||{};window.perfMetrics.onFirstInputDelay=function(a){d.push(a);m()}})();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     (function() {
    if ('PerformanceObserver' in window &amp;&amp; 'PerformancePaintTiming' in window) {
      window.__bufferedPerformance = [];
      var ob = new PerformanceObserver(function(e) {
        window.__bufferedPerformance.push.apply(window.__bufferedPerformance,e.getEntries());
      });
      ob.observe({entryTypes:['paint']});
    }
    window.__bufferedErrors = [];
    window.onerror = function(message, url, line, column, error) {
      window.__bufferedErrors.push({
        message: message,
        url: url,
        line: line,
        column: column,
        error: error
      });
      return false;
    };
    window.__initialData = {
      pending: true,
      waiting: []
    };
    function notifyLoaded(item, data) {
      item.pending = false;
      item.data = data;
      for (var i = 0;i &lt; item.waiting.length; ++i) {
        item.waiting[i].resolve(item.data);
      }
      item.waiting = [];
    }
    function notifyError(item, msg) {
      item.pending = false;
      item.error = new Error(msg);
      for (var i = 0;i &lt; item.waiting.length; ++i) {
        item.waiting[i].reject(item.error);
      }
      item.waiting = [];
    }
    window.__initialDataLoaded = function(initialData) {
      notifyLoaded(window.__initialData, initialData);
    };
    window.__initialDataError = function(msg) {
      notifyError(window.__initialData, msg);
    };
    window.__additionalData = {};
    window.__pendingAdditionalData = function(paths) {
      for (var i = 0;i &lt; paths.length; ++i) {
        window.__additionalData[paths[i]] = {
      pending: true,
      waiting: []
        };
      }
    };
    window.__additionalDataLoaded = function(path, data) {
      if (path in window.__additionalData) {
        notifyLoaded(window.__additionalData[path], data);
      } else {
        console.error('Unexpected additional data loaded "' + path + '"');
      }
    };
    window.__additionalDataError = function(path, msg) {
      if (path in window.__additionalData) {
        notifyError(window.__additionalData[path], msg);
      } else {
        console.error('Unexpected additional data encountered an error "' + path + '": ' + msg);
      }
    };
  })();
    </script>
    <link href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-76x76-precomposed.png/4272e394f5ad.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76"/>
    <link href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png/02ba5abf9861.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120"/>
    <link href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png/419a6f9c7454.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152"/>
    <link href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-167x167-precomposed.png/a24e58112f06.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="167x167"/>
    <link href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-180x180-precomposed.png/85a358fb3b7d.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="180x180"/>
    <link href="/static/images/ico/favicon-192.png/68d99ba29cc8.png" rel="icon" sizes="192x192"/>
    <link color="#262626" href="/static/images/ico/favicon.svg/fc72dd4bfde8.svg" rel="mask-icon"/>
    <link href="/static/images/ico/favicon.ico/36b3ee2d91ed.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link href="android-app://com.instagram.android/https/instagram.com/_u/gelsonfonteles/" rel="alternate"/>
    <meta content="Instagram" property="al:ios:app_name"/>
    <meta content="389801252" property="al:ios:app_store_id"/>
    <meta content="instagram://user?username=gelsonfonteles" property="al:ios:url"/>
    <meta content="Instagram" property="al:android:app_name"/>
    <meta content="com.instagram.android" property="al:android:package"/>
    <meta content="https://www.instagram.com/_u/gelsonfonteles/" property="al:android:url"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/" rel="canonical"/>
    <meta content="94.2k Followers, 323 Following, 620 Posts - See Instagram photos and videos from Gelson Fonteles ???? (@gelsonfonteles)" name="description"/>
    <meta content="profile" property="og:type"/>
    <meta content="https://scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/44c2bf3c9657d797afd661cd7026e189/5C9C5435/t51.2885-19/s150x150/46263173_2475614175787091_1415254353245110272_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com" property="og:image"/>
    <meta content="Gelson Fonteles ???? (@gelsonfonteles) • Instagram photos and videos" property="og:title"/>
    <meta content="94.2k Followers, 323 Following, 620 Posts - See Instagram photos and videos from Gelson Fonteles ???? (@gelsonfonteles)" property="og:description"/>
    <meta content="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/" property="og:url"/>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
     {"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"Person","name":"Gelson Fonteles \ud83d\udd8b\ud83d\udd04","alternateName":"@gelsonfonteles","description":"Fortaleza - CE , 23 anos!\nENCOMENDAS : Whats App: (85) 99760-7606","url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/gelson.fonteles","mainEntityofPage":{"@type":"ProfilePage","@id":"https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/gelsonfonteles\/","interactionStatistic":{"@type":"InteractionCounter","interactionType":"http:\/\/schema.org\/FollowAction","userInteractionCount":"94237"}},"image":"https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/static\/images\/ico\/favicon-200.png\/ab6eff595bb1.png","email":"gelsonfontelesart@gmail.com"}
    </script>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/" hreflang="x-default" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=en" hreflang="en" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=fr" hreflang="fr" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=it" hreflang="it" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=de" hreflang="de" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es" hreflang="es" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=zh-cn" hreflang="zh-cn" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=zh-tw" hreflang="zh-tw" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=ja" hreflang="ja" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=ko" hreflang="ko" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=pt" hreflang="pt" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=pt-br" hreflang="pt-br" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=af" hreflang="af" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=cs" hreflang="cs" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=da" hreflang="da" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=el" hreflang="el" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=fi" hreflang="fi" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=hr" hreflang="hr" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=hu" hreflang="hu" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=id" hreflang="id" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=ms" hreflang="ms" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=nb" hreflang="nb" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=nl" hreflang="nl" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=pl" hreflang="pl" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=ru" hreflang="ru" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=sk" hreflang="sk" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=sv" hreflang="sv" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=th" hreflang="th" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=tl" hreflang="tl" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=tr" hreflang="tr" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=hi" hreflang="hi" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=bn" hreflang="bn" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=gu" hreflang="gu" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=kn" hreflang="kn" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=ml" hreflang="ml" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=mr" hreflang="mr" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=pa" hreflang="pa" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=ta" hreflang="ta" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=te" hreflang="te" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=ne" hreflang="ne" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=si" hreflang="si" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=ur" hreflang="ur" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=vi" hreflang="vi" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=bg" hreflang="bg" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=fr-ca" hreflang="fr-ca" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=ro" hreflang="ro" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=sr" hreflang="sr" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=uk" hreflang="uk" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=zh-hk" hreflang="zh-hk" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-uy" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-gt" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-pe" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-cl" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-ar" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-mx" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-bo" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-cu" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-pa" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-ve" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-do" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-co" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-pr" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-cr" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-ec" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-ni" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-hn" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-sv" rel="alternate"/>
    <link href="https://www.instagram.com/gelsonfonteles/?hl=es-la" hreflang="es-py" rel="alternate"/>
  ```